# Container expanding beyond mobile device size

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a problem where I'm looking to make sure my content doesn't exceed the full height of the device, but the approach I have taken has led to the footer being hidden by the browser menu and the need to scroll to see on smaller mobile devices. Should I set a wrapper div that makes sure the `<main>` and `<footer>` don't go beyond the browser height?

**Code:**

```
<body className={`flex flex-col min-h-screen bg-gray-200 ${inter.className}`}>
  <main className="relative flex-grow bg-[url('../public/windows.jpg')] bg-cover bg-center">
    ...
  </main>
  <footer className="flex-row bottom-0 bg-gradient-to-t from-[#225ad9] to-[#5891EA]">
    ...
  </footer>
</body>
```

**Issue:**

[image: overflow]